# Time Estimation of Wake Up from Anesthesia

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One need to anesthetize dog to take a surgery of it. Dog wakes up when the amount of remaining anesthesia is less than 800(mg) in its blood.

The remaining amount of anesthesia reduces into half of the total amount of 6 hours before, and its reduction always depends on the remaining total amount of anesthesia in the blood.

If a veterinarian inject 2400(mg) of anesthesia into a Dog, how long would it take for the dog to wake up?

---

To solve above question, I can easily get to the level of 1200(mg) in 6hrs but I cannot determine when it would get to the level of 800(mg).

The question says reduction only depends on the remaining total amount of the anesthesia in the blood. How could one use this clue to get the proper answer?

Comment: "Dog wakes up when the amount of remaining anesthesia is *more than* 800(mg) in its blood. " Do you mean "...less than..." ?

Comment: @Evargalo yes. Edited OP

Comment: The level of anesthetia at time x (in hours) is $f(x)=24e^{-xln2/6}$...

Comment: @Evargalo could you elaborate how you get to your f(x)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life#Formulas_for_half-life_in_exponential_decay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The level of anesthesia in the dog's blood is defined by its half-life period. Such functions can be represented by a negative exponential function, as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life#Formulas_for_half-life_in_exponential_decay.

From $f(x)=Ae^{-\lambda x}$, the informations $f(0)=2400$ and $f(x+6)=f(x)/2$ (for instance, $f(6)=1200$) allow us to determine $A$ and $\lambda$:

$A=2400$ and $\lambda=\frac{ln2}{6}$

Hence $f(x)=2400e^{-\frac{ln2}{6} x}$

From there you can easily solve $f(x)=800$ for $x$ and get:

$x_{wakeup}=6*\frac{ln 3}{ln2}\approx9.51 hour\approx 9h30'30''$